# destructuring and returning result in fat arrow function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Consider a React & Redux environment, where a component receives some state. Let's use the following example:

```
state = {
  users: ['bob', 'alice'],
  history: {param: 1},
  releases: [1, 2],
  categories: [1, 2, 3],
  store: {dispatch: () => (), subscribe: () => ()},
  contact: {message: ""},
  hosts: ['company1', 'company2'],
  experiences: ['xp1', 'xp2'],
}
```

Right now, we write our components as follow:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

@connect(state => ({
  hosts: state.hosts,
  experiences: state.experiences,
  categories: state.categories,
}))
export default class Home extends Component {
  ...
}
```

I've been trying to think of a way to reduce the size of this state mapping function passed to **connect**. Here are a few examples:

```
@connect(({hosts, experiences, categories}) => ({hosts, experiences, categories})

@connect(state => _.pick(state, ['hosts', 'experiences', 'categories'])

@connect(({users, history, releases, store, contact, ...rest}) => rest)
```

Nothing satisfactory readability and DRY wise.
Why is it that we have a spread and rest operators, but no way to reduce this redundant mapping ? Something like one of the following examples:

```
@connect(({hosts, experiences, categories}) => ...)

@connect(...({hosts, experiences, categories}))

@connect(=> ({hosts, experiences, categories}))

@connect(({hosts, experiences, categories}))
```

Would be a lot simpler.
Might there be a better writing style that I'm not aware of ?

Comment: `@connect(({hosts, experiences, categories}) => ({hosts, experiences, categories}))` should work fine. What do you exactly mean by `Nothing satisfactory`?

Comment: All the examples that I gave work fine, this is a matter of readability. I do not like the duplication of `({hosts, experiences, categories})`. It takes O(2N) to write.

In that regard, the lodash function `_.pick()` actually does a good job of reducing duplication, but I haven't evaluated if there is any performance loss. Also, coworkers didn't seem to find it readable enough

Comment: I can't think of anything, but is readability really an issue with that code? It looks great. Your devs should be able to read this crystal clear, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do what you want with 'pure' js syntax.
If you want to avoid repetitions and maintain readability, creating own mapping function factory seems to be the best solution.

```
function fromState(...props) {
  return state => {
    const importedState = {};
    props.forEach(prop => importedState[prop] = state[prop]);
    return importedState;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it inside connect like this:

```
@connect(fromState('hosts', 'experiences', 'categories'))
```